# RxJava sequence contains no elements error

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm using RxJava and everything looks good except in one case where it throws these errors.

```
 Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Sequence contains no elements
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:118)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.onCompleted(OperatorTake.java:56)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter$FilterSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeFilter.java:99)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.slowpath(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:134)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable$IterableProducer.request(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:89)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1$1.request(OperatorTake.java:109)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.setProducer(OperatorTake.java:93)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter$FilterSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeFilter.java:104)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:63)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFromIterable.call(OnSubscribeFromIterable.java:34)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter.call(OnSubscribeFilter.java:45)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter.call(OnSubscribeFilter.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:250)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:147)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:77)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitScalar(OperatorMerge.java:399)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.tryEmit(OperatorMerge.java:357)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onNext(OperatorMerge.java:852)
at rx.internal.operato
```

Edit:
The problem is in the function`NumberObservables::mergeNumberAndName`,

```
public static Observable<Trailer> mergeTrailerType(Trailer trailer) {
    String id = number.getId();
    return Observable.from(Store.names())
            .first(name -> id.equals(name.getId()))
            .map(name -> {
                number.setName(name);
                return number;
            });
}
```

As I can see `first` makes the problem but I cant replace it with take(1) or firstOrDefault (can't find `getId()`). Can it work with `single`?

Answer (score 1):

you probably apply somewhere at the stream (`NumberObservables::getByNumber` or `NumberObservables::mergeNumberAndName`) the `single()` operator, it can be observed at the stack trace here:

```
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:118)
```

`single()` expects source `Observable` that emit only one item, and notifies error of `NoSuchElementException` if source Observable emit no items, from the stack trace, this is happens probably due to some filter you have applied:

```
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter$FilterSubscriber.onCompleted(OnSubscribeFilter.java:99)
```

Comment: Yes, I found it now, I'm applying the `.first` operatior in `NumberObservables::mergeNumberAndName` and that's why it throws the exception. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: well, it's hard to tell without understanding your logic, you can use `firstOrDefault` to provide default value, but generally you want the single item from the Observable while there is non, so refine your logic to what you're expecting to be emitted in this case

Comment: I changed the question with the function `NumberObservables::mergeNumberAndName` and other details. You can see it.

Comment: you can use `filter()` instead, but that depends on your expectations,  with filter you can have no items or multiple, if that logically acceptable in your case, so this is the more appropriate operator to use here.